# New Boot Messages as of 22.04.1

Tags: boot

Prior to upgrading to 22.04.1 the screen never presented boot [error] messages. Now I get a series of messages that I'm clueless about. Would anyone know anything about the messages shown in the image below?

[image]

Comment: Ignore them. This has been asked multiple times and you can easily find the Q&As just by searching the messages here.

Comment: I did search, both before and after.  Maybe you search better than I so please show me your results that specifically deals with Ubuntu 22.04.01 where the advice is to ignore the messages.